# How to match rows for text-similarity in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, search, similarity

I have lots of songs listed in my MySQL table.

The real data in MySQL: `"The All-American Rejects"`

What I want to match: `"All American Rejects"`

A basic approach would be removing non-alphabetical characters ("-" specifically in here) and doing a `"LIKE %All American Rejects%"`. However, "-" may not be the only character that I would have to replace and also I am not searching `"All-American Rejects"`, instead, I search `"All American Rejects"`; so, I have to but cannot remove "-" from rows (technically possible but not feasible because of the performance).

In PHP, there is a function named `soundex()` 
(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

I think, I need something similar to that one or something similar to Levenshtein technic.

I am stuck and any help would be wonderful.

**update:**

Some other examples: (data stored in db -> search term)

- `Dark Horse feat. Juicy J` -> `Dark Horse FT Juicy J`
- `Prism`-> `PRISM Deluxe'
- `Thrift Shop ->`Thrift Shop (feat. Wanz)'
- ...

Comment: Are there any other matching rules we should be aware of? (other than replacing some characters with spaces)

Comment: @Vatev I've updated the question with some more examples

Comment: Did you try a [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) ?